# Error creating Dataset in Wave using salesforce

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

Whenever I try to create a dataset in Wave Analytics using Salesforce,I get this error which says : WARNING: Your dataflow definition contains errors that will cause your dataflow to fail.

Fix these sfdcDigest node errors and then upload the file again:

In the '160' node, the 'Disable_VRules__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'Hire_Date__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'License_Allocated__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'License_Pool__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'License_Type__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'Physical_Locale__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'Product_Family__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'Re_Hire_Date__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User. In the '160' node, the 'Term_Date__c' field doesn't exist or isn't accessible to the Integration User.

Comment: looks like the user doesn't have access to those objects, hence why you are unable to create the dataset

Comment: For anyone else coming here, I'm just reposting a comment from below. 
These Profiles - Analytics Cloud Integration User and Analytics Cloud Security User are the profiles that need Read access to the fields if its not completely clear from the error message (like it was for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Einstein Analytics dataflows run through the Integration User. If the
>   Integration User profile does not have visibility for a field in the
>   dataflow, it will cause the following error:
>
> Error executing node sfdcDigest_Node: Field [Field_Name] is not
>   available. Verify that the field exists and that the Analytics Cloud
>   Integration User profile has Read level access on the field.

[Dataflow Error "Field is not available" in Einstein Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227661&type=1)

**Determine the related Object**

> Retrieve the dataflow JSON through the following steps:
>
> 1. Gear Icon > Data Monitor
> 2. Change view to Dataflow View
> 3. Click the dropdown options on the right side for the target dataflow and select Download
> 4. Open the resulting file in your favorite JSON editor Locate the specified node to determine the object, this will generally appear as
>      follows:

```
"sfdcDigest_Node": {

    "action": "sfdcDigest",

    "parameters": {

      "object": "Object",
```

**Confirm Field Level Security settings**

> Review the Field Level Security for the Object within the Profile
>   assigned to the Einstein Analytics Integration User. Ensure the
>   profile has Read Access on the field(s) listed in the error. More
>   information about managing FLS can be found here:

- Setting Field Permissions in Permission Sets and Profiles

**Check Managed Package access**

> Review the Custom Fields on the Object. Determine if they are part of
>   a managed package. Ensure that the Integration User has the necessary
>   permissions and/or licenses to access the managed package that
>   contains the target fields. Methods for granting access to managed
>   package components vary, reach out to the package creator for
>   assistance granting access to its components. Restart Dataflow Once
>   these items have been updated, you can re-run the dataflow by
>   selecting Start from the dropdown menu in the Data Monitor.

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it helped you resolve your issue, =), glad i could help @Ravi Deshmukh

Comment: Any ideas if the running user actually have access to the fields, in fact they can edit them from the object edit page?

Comment: Actually you are right but perhaps if anyone is running the same issue, is not the profile of the current user is the profile of: Analytics Cloud Integration User and Analytics Cloud Security User, that is why i was getting confused